# Excel: blank and/or lines in fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, excel-2010

As of this moment I’m working with an Excel file, there´s a field that are not showing data unsless I move the borders.

[image]

That means that the field is having either blank spaces or a line

I try many things to get rid of the lines or blank spaces, because this is repeating itself in several fields and change it manually is no longer feasible

In short, I have this:

```
bb@123.com
-----------

bb@123.com

-----------
```

and i need this

```
bb@123.com
-----------
bb@123.com
-----------
```

The file would eventually become a CSV just in case.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `=SUBSTITUTE (E2,CHAR(10),"")`

Comment: Select the hidden characters in your text and copy it, then open Find and Replace and paste the value in the find box, put nothing in the replace box and click replace all. do these step with all the remaining hidden values.